# ng-style does not update based on eventListner

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After creating the eventlistner it waits until for a postMessage and then updates the IframeHeight, however it does not change the height immediately, the change is only triggered on the ui when I perform some activity (like click, type in an input box etc).

```
$scope.getIframeHeight = function(){
    $scope.IframeHeight = "800";
    if (!window.addEventListener) {
        // IE8 support (could also use an addEventListener shim)
        window.attachEvent('onmessage', $scope.handleMessage);
    } else {
        window.addEventListener('message', $scope.handleMessage, false);
    }
};

$scope.handleMessage = function(event){
    var origin = event.origin || event.originalEvent.origin; // For Chrome, the origin property is in the event.originalEvent object.
    if (origin !== "http://localhost:8060")
        return;
    console.log('parent received message!:  ',event.data);
    $scope.IframeHeight = event.data;
};


<iframe class='iframe' id='iframe' scrolling='no' ng-style="{'height': IframeHeight + 'px'}" width="100%"
        frameborder='0' ng-src="{{trustSrc(data.IframeSRC)}}">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't know why the changes made to $scope.IframeHeight not reflected, but this worked for me:

```
$scope.handleMessage = function(event){
var origin = event.origin || event.originalEvent.origin; // For Chrome, the origin property is in the event.originalEvent object.
if (origin !== "http://localhost:8060")
    return;
console.log('parent received message!:  ',event.data);
***$scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.IframeHeight = event.data;
    });***
};
```

Comment: Here you made use of $scope.$apply, which is basically equivalent to call the digest cycle of the angular scope manually. Now whenever you change some scope data outside angular variable then the changes will not be reflected because the digest cycle is not triggered in that case. Here in your case, you attached event listener in plain javascript way which is not in the angular visibility, hence calling the scope digest cycle manually using `$scope.$apply` worked. For more, you can look into the angular scope life cycle and how it is executed

Comment: @Harpreet thanks I just started with angular and still weak on the concepts, it would be great if you could share places where I can start